# live under the same roof [as/with] a woman

Tags: meaning, as

I take that both of them are used, but I don't understand the sentence with 'as'. Many natives said that the two sentences mean the same thing fundamentally, but I don't get it the 'as' part. They said 'as' takes the role of preposition 'like', but doesn't 'like' mean 'in the same way'? If I live a lazy life while my wife works diligently, could I still say "I live under the same roof as a woman"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence using "with" is incorrect, but often used informally.

Here "as" is used as a preposition in the sense of "introducing a basis for comparison"

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Preposition

> I live under the same roof as (the roof that) a woman (lives under).

Means the same as

> I live under a roof with a woman.

Since we all live under roofs, this just means:

> I live with a woman.

Bringing the roof into the sentence, and mentioning that it is the same roof, are all details that the listener would have assumed anyway, so serve as emphasis.

> "You fly airplanes?"
>   "Yes, with wings and engines and everything."

This particular phrase is an idiomatic way of emphasising this.

If you really want to go crazy with it:

> I live under the exact same roof as a woman - we have got a couch, and cushions and a stove and everything.

Comment: Thanks, so does 'as' work as a conjunction, not a preposition?

Comment: No, it's a preposition because it expresses the relation of the roof to the woman

Comment: Then would you be so nice and make the longer version of 'as' phrase of "The news came as a shock." as you did in "as (the roof that) a woman (lives under)"?

Comment: One more thing please, what is the name of the violation of grammar in the sentence of 'with'? I mean, where should I find the related grammar rule?

Comment: In "the news came as a shock" the word "as" is the preposition in the sense "in the role of". E.g. "The ghost came as a crow". "He came to the masquerade as a jester". It's a different sense

Comment: The problem with the sentence "I live under the same roof with a woman" is that the adjective "same" doesn't have an object - same as what? It can't be woman or that means "I live under the same roof as a woman with that woman" which is silly. It could work with context: "I lived under that roof with my parents. I live under the same roof with a woman". but that means something different.